# Context-Sensitive Help like Cisco iOS (Switch and Router Management CLI)

Tags: bash, shell, keyboard-shortcuts, cisco

I haven't found anything like this available for linux but as a Network Tech/Admin I really appreciate the good old Cisco iOS approach to listing optional commands. Where Bash would tell me "command not recognized, are you looking for a command in the following packages:" Cisco iOS has a more intuitive system where:

```
Router> Command Argum*TAB*
Router> Command Argument
```

Autocompletion like Linux / UNIX. 

**And**

```
Router> Command ?
Argument, Argument2, Argument3....
```

This is true following the full length of available arguments for any command see: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/configfun/command/reference/ffun_r/frfusing.html

**And**

```
Router> ?
Command, Command2, Command3, Command4....
```

Linux has a lot of commands, I definitely see `| less` as a necessity to most of the outputs here.

If you get the drift, what are some available packages that may do something similar or implement functionality that lists available commands and or arguments to those commands as demonstrated above? 
Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Historically always been tab completion for file names.  For more, check the `bash-completion` package from Ubuntu/Mint or equivalent for your distro

Comment: Right I suppose I could have ignored that portion of the question, the important part is the ability to display available commands and more importantly _all_ of the available argument options that follow a given command and perhaps given arguments or statements already typed in your "to be" line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan too of the Cisco Auto completion function in terms of tab to auto complete should one exist and "?" to view what's next.

However as already stated this already exists for most Linux OS systems (have confirmed this myself through Kali Linux and Ubuntu) where tab will function the same way and keying tab twice will function like the "?" query.

I might be able to help more do you have a specific OS you are using right now? Some of the more stripped down may not have this functionality.

References: https://www.howtogeek.com/195207/use-tab-completion-to-type-commands-faster-on-any-operating-system/

Comment: Ahoy That Boi! Yes of course there's double tab to list some available commands but I've never seen it display arguments. I was working on debian based systems and would also greatly approve of this on CentOS, but generally speaking knowing what packages may apply this ability to any Linux Distribution would be most preferable.